# How can I OCR two different languages in Adobe Acrobat?

Tags: adobe, ocr, acrobat

I got a scanned menu from a hongkong restaurant, and I need to make the .pdf file searchable or in plain text format. I tried Adobe Acrobat OCR, it worked perfectly however the menu is in traditional Chinese and English, for Acrobat OCR I can only set it to read either English or Chinese, so I ended up with two files for each PDF.

Is there a smart way to let Acrobat read both languages?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a workaround, if the English and Chinese texts are not mixed.

If the document allows it, you could use the crop tool to crop to the text in one language, run OCR, undo the crop, and crop to the text in the other language, and run OCR. OCR is applied only to the cropped area, and this is the way you can circumvent the problem with the "document contains rendered text" error message by Acrobat.

Otherwise, place a feature request with Adobe.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no way in Adobe Acrobat.

I suggest to get another powerful OCR capable to auto-detect and process multiple languages at the same time, and then create PDF or some other output.  I use ABBYY FineReader.  Trial version is available from their website.